# git subtree useless merge

Tags: git, shell, git-subtree

I added a **subtree** into my project **demo** this way

```
$ git subtree add --prefix=plugins/plugone plugone master --squash
$ tree .

demo
|___.git
|___plugins
       |___plugone

$ git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate

* 200e94c (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Merge commit 'f9a745bb60b3e5816f918c0ec736714bd362bce7' as 'plugins/plugone'
| \
|  * f9a745b Squashed 'plugins/plugone/' content from commit 5c4a153
* 947ebfe bla bla
```

So far so good, I'm happy with **subtree**. Then I edited a file into the **subtree** plugone and committed and **subtree push**ed

```
* 07b3046 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) plugone append #1
* 200e94c Merge commit 'f9a745bb60b3e5816f918c0ec736714bd362bce7' as 'plugins/plugone'
| \
|  * f9a745b Squashed 'plugins/plugone/' content from commit 5c4a153
* 947ebfe bla bla
```

I noticed that after I updated **plugone** from my project **demo** through `git subtree push --prefix=plugins/plugone plugone master`, when I run

```
$ git subtree pull --prefix=plugins/plugone plugone master --squash
```

I expected this to do **nothing**, but I noticed new commits in the **demo** project:

```
*   a5ab686 (HEAD -> master) Merge commit 'c8cd6206950dc45196cf6fd1f17e8587a115fee6'
|\
| * c8cd620 Squashed 'plugins/plugone/' changes from 5c4a153..1fd84fe
* | 07b3046 (origin/master) plugone append #1
* |   200e94c Merge commit 'f9a745bb60b3e5816f918c0ec736714bd362bce7' as 'plugins/plugone'
|\ \
| |/
| * f9a745b Squashed 'plugins/plugone/' content from commit 5c4a153
* 947ebfe blabla
```

This is very embarrassing because it means that my colleagues and I have to run **git subtree pull** after every **git subtree push** which IMO doesn't make much sense.

How to prevent this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well another way does exist to do that but in a bit harder way (more command to run). 
Instead of using [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree), I tried **git read-tree/merge** and it gives something IMO nicer...

The advantage is that I don't need to install extra tools...

Here is a helpful article that describes well how to use subtree concept manually https://delicious-insights.com/en/posts/mastering-git-subtrees/#subtrees-step-by-step